# QTP open more that one tests a at time

Tags: process, qtp

We all know that it is a bit of a headache to be able to only have one test or project open with QTP at a time.

I would like to find out a way to either open two tests at a time or for that matter launch QTP twice (two parallel processes).

Thanks in advance for the answers/ideas.

PS> I am not able to use VMwares for now...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very simple, upgrade to [UFT 11.50](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-DKilwaiyGE) which supports opening multiple tests at the same time.

Comment: it's my company's call so if it was for me I would have done this long time ago ;)

Comment: Hi Motti. Could you please tell me where did you find this spec (supports multiple tests at the same time) so I can make a strong case for upgrading to my boss? Thanks!

Comment: I don't know when you can find a full list other than [this overview](http://www8.hp.com/us/en/software-solutions/software.html?compURI=1172122). You can download a trial version and have a look at `Help -> What's New`

Comment: OK got it by now. When you download a Trial version you also have access to a lot of documents that specify the new features more closely. Thanks for all your help Motti!

Comment: Not a very good anwer, is it? I correct answer to the actual question would be: No, it's not possible in QTP 11.00. 

Also, UTF 11.50 is so unstable that I wouldn't recommend anyone to upgrade unless they can test it thoroughly on their system(s) first. My company has tried it for a few weeks and concluded that we have to stick with 11.00, since 11.50 is both bugged and unstable.

Comment: @Motti, Is upgrading to 11.50 the only solution?

Comment: @Pacerier this answer is over two years old, I would recommend upgrading to UFT 12.02. Your license is perpetual so there's no cost in upgrading and QTP11 is pretty ancient (it doesn't support most current browsers).

Comment: @Motti, Sadly companies sticking with legacy is a real problem.

Answer (score 0):

You go to File > Add> Existing Test